# How to copy an EFI partition from one device to another?

Tags: partitioning, uefi

So here is the problem.  I have a MacMini2.1 that I am trying to install Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 on.

This little machine from 2007 used a 32bit EFI but the OS could be 64 bit.

I found a web site that had instructions for creating a USB Flash install for Ubuntu 22.04.  The Live USB boots and I can try Ubuntu. That works.  Install Ubuntu runs, but after it runs I need to copy the files in /dev/sdb1 to /dev/sda1.

The USB Flash EFI is 36M, it is /dev/sdb1 and is formatted FAT32.  The SSD in the Mini has an EFI of 500M, it is /dev/sda1 and is formatted FAT32.

So how do I copy all the files and directories from /dev/sdb1 to /dev/sda1?

Thanks

Dennis

Comment: You typically do not copy files, but just reinstall grub in UEFI mode to sda1. If sda is internal drive it will then boot from /EFI/ubuntu. If external drive, it will boot from /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi. If you copy the ESP, you have to create new UEFI entry using efibootmgr to have correct GUID/partUUID of new ESP, edit /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg to have correct UUID of install & edit fstab to have correct UUID of ESP. Easier just to install grub. You can use Boot-Repair or chroot into install.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: After Ubuntu installation is complete, Use **Continue Testing** option to remain in the Live USB. The EFI System partition (ESP) in the USB drive (`/dev/sdb1`) should be mounted at `/boot/efi`. Navigate to this location using Nautilius (AKA Files) Mount the /dev/sda1` partition by double clicking on it (or using the Disks app). Drag and drop all the files and folders from one to the other. **Note**, simply copying the files will not be sufficient. You will also need to install grub again with appropriate options for the boot folder/partition and system (`/`) partition in the internal disks.